# Separating a matrix into sub-matrices in Fortran

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran

Suppose I have a 2-D array such that the first column is composed of only two integers 1 and 2:

```
1 5 1 7 0.5                   
2 4 5 6 0.1       
1 9 3 4 0.6        
2 8 7 2 0.2
```

I want to separate two matrices out of this, such that the first column of each contains the same integer (so the first column of first matrix contains only integer 1, same goes for 2 in the second matrix).
So it would become:

```
1 5 1 7 0.5
1 9 3 4 0.6
```

and

```
2 4 5 6 0.1              
2 8 7 2 0.2
```

I don't know exactly how to start. I was thinking of using the count at the beginning (well, because I have a way larger matrix with 10 different integers in the first column), then according to the counted number of each integer I construct the dimension of each [sub]matrix. After that, the only thing I could think of is the count(mask), and if the value is true it's then added to the matrix by if statement.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what are you trying to achieve? Also, could you post any code you already tried and the result you got?

Comment: I can only think of doing this with two loops. One to figure out the size of each array and another to assign the values.

Comment: Actually I think there is an intrinsic function for that, but I'm still not sure what OP is looking for

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with matrices: do you mean Fortran arrays in the program (you want to create multiple arrays in the program from one which already is in the memory), or regular arrangements of numbers in files (you have one input file and want to create multiple output files)?  The example you provide has integers and real numbers, if you are thinking about the first case, do you want to store them in the same array (it will have to be real), or can you store them in two (one for integer numbers, one for real numbers)?

Comment: Excuse me if it was unclear. Yes I have one input file and I want create multiple output files out of it. And thanks for the notice that they to be real. because I want to store them in the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have mixed types (`integer` and `real`) in the same array in Fortran, so I will suppose all data are `real` in the 2-dim array:

```
program split
  implicit none

  real, allocatable :: a(:, :), b(:, :)
  integer :: i, ids = 10
  integer, allocatable :: id(:), seq(:)

  a = reshape([real :: 1, 5, 1, 7, 0.5, &
                     & 2, 4, 5, 6, 0.1, &
                     & 1, 9, 3, 4, 0.6, &
                     & 2, 8, 7, 2, 0.2], [5, 4])
  seq = [(i, i = 1, size(a, 2))]
  do i = 1, ids
    print*, "i = ", i
    ! here we are creating a vector with all the line indices that start with i
    ! e.g. for i = 1 we get id = [1, 3], for i = 2 we get [2, 4], for i = 3 we get [], ...
    id =  pack(seq, a(1,:) == i)
    ! here we use a Fortran feature named vector-subscript
    b = a(:, id)
    print*, b
  end do
end
```

If you want the first column(or any column) to be `integer`, you can declare it as a separated array, and use the same vector subscripts to gather the desired lines.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have only one question please. I'm writing my code in Fortran 90. Everything is clear for me with your 2003 version, except the seq = [i...], which I couldn't find out how to right it in F90.

Comment: `seq =(/(i, i = 1, size(a, 2))/)` But I am using automatic allocation in the whole example, that didn't exist in Fonrtran 90. You may have to allocate the array seq before with `allocate(seq(1:size(a, 2))`. Same goes to all other allocatable arrays.